# How to select filed position by votes MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've got a database table called servers with three columns 'id', 'name', and 'votes'.

How can I select the position of column id 5 by votes?

Example, I want to check which position server 3 is in by votes in my competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT id, name, votes FROM servers ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 2,1;
```

`LIMIT a, b` means "give me b rows, starting at row a", and `a` is zero-based.

---

OK, I misunderstood. Now. Suppose your server has 27 votes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM servers WHERE votes < 27;
```

Your server's rank will be 1 plus the result; ties are possible (i.e. ranks will be like 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7, 9 etc.).

Comment: and how can i print the number?

Comment: Which number? I thought you want the 3rd place.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, you want to know the rank of the server with ID 3?

Comment: yes i want to get the rank if the server with id 3 according to votes

Comment: I see. You can do what Whoopska says, or retrieve the ordered query result and loop through until you found id 3. It depends on whether you just want the rank of one server, or if you want the ranks of all servers.

Comment: i want the rank of only one server, can u give me an example code?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM servers WHERE votes < {$r['votes']} ORDER BY votes DESC

am i right?

Comment: @Yoni: `COUNT` is an aggregate, so you only get one single result, there's no such thing as an ordering on that. Do go an try it at the mysql command line interface, you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, you are asking how to find the rank of the row with id 5 in a list of servers sorted by votes. There is a complex solution, which requires sorting, but the easier solution which can be done in O(log(n)) space and O(n) time is to simply measure the number of votes for id = 5

```
select votes from servers where id = 5;
```

and then walk through the database and add one for every server encountered that has smaller number of votes. Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
select count(*) from servers where votes <= %votes
```

It is excessive to sort this (O(nlog(n) time) when you can simple iterate through the entire list once and gather all the information you need.